# Scope issue with vector inside class

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Dict
{
public:
    string line;
    int wordcount;
    string word;
    vector<string> words;
    Dict(string f)
    {
        ifstream myFile;
        myFile.open(f.c_str());
        if (myFile.is_open())
        {
            while(!myFile.eof())
            {
                myFile >> word;
                words.push_back(word);
            }
            cout << endl << "Wordcount: " << wordcount << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "ERROR couldn't open file" << endl;
        myFile.close();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dict d("test.txt");
    cout << words.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error that words vector was not declared in main().

How can I make this visible to the compiler, since I already defined it in the class. Once an object is instantiated and the constructor is invoked, shouldn't words vector be created? But the compiler doesn't notice this.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`words` is a member in your `Dict` object `d`:

```
int main() {
    Dict d("test.txt");
    cout << d.words.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you could have several objects of that class, each with its own instance of `words`, how is the compiler supposed to know which one you mean?

Just tell the compiler where to find the words:

```
cout << d.words.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `d.words` because `words` is a member of `d`.

In classes, each member, either variable or function belongs to an object. If you have two objects:

```
Dict d1("text1.txt");
Dict d2("text1.txt");
```

Then there is no way for the compiler to understand by `words` if you mean `words` in `d1` or `d2` unless you tell it. The way you tell it is to put the object name, followed by `.` followed by member name.

That is `d1.words` and `d2.words` are two different vectors.